# How to create email content type to multipart/mixed in php

Tags: php, email

I have a website contact form that sends as an email to my iPhone. The problem is I am getting the following message:
"This message cannot be displayed because of the way it is formatted. Ask the sender to send it again using a different format or email program. multipart/mixed"

Is this has something to do with email content-type and how to fix it in my PHP code.

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$sender_email."" . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n";
$body = "--$boundary\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message_body));
$sentMail = mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You specify the `Content-Type` as a header string.

Assuming you are appending your headers with the standard dot notation, you would use:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed";
```

And later this would become the fourth parameter of your `mail()` function:

```
mail($address, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Here's a basic example:

```
$address = 'sample@sample.com';
$subject = 'Subject';
$message = 'Message';
$headers = "From: My Name<something@something.com>\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: something@something.com \n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed";

mail($address, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: it is already stated as such. I still have a problem. I am having also attachment in the form. Could that be the problem?